# Запись log сообщения в файл P7 library

Tags: c++, логирование

Как записать сообщение в файл? У меня только создает txt файл и все.

```
#include "P7_Client.h"
#include "P7_Trace.h" 

  bool CLogHandler::Init()
    {
        IP7_Client *l_pClient = P7_Create_Client(TM("/P7.Sink=FileTxt"));
        if (l_pClient == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error IP7_Client" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        IP7_Trace * l_pTrace = P7_Create_Trace(l_pClient, TM("Test"));
        l_pTrace->P7_WARNING(0, TM("Test"));
        l_pClient->Release();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

P7 - асинхронный логгер, вызов Log функции независим от записи данных, таким образом они снижают задержки на вызов функции.

Судя по исходному коду, flush в файл может происходить в одном из 3-х случаев:

1. заполнился буфер для хранения сообщений библиотеки.
2. приложение штатно завершается, освобождается и trace.
3. Использовали `P7_Set_Crash_Handler` и упали с ошибкой.

Таким образом, записать можно следующим образом:

1. передать несколько сообщений для заполнения буфера. Причём,
   последнее сообщение с вероятностью 99% останется в буфере. Оно
   записывается при освобождении Trace.
2. вызвать `Trace->Release()` столько раз, сколько вызывали `Create_Trace`

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/188105)

Comment: @br3t, спасибо, исправил. Так должно быть понятнее.